# Change Font in entire google form

Tags: google-forms

I am new to google forms and And all the text and options are in big font. Can some one tell me how to reduce the font for entire form.

I have gone through :
http://www.techrepublic.com/article/google-forms-customize-colors-images-and-fonts/

but was no use

Thanks
Aditya

Answer (score 0):

This article (still shown as the top result for related search queries on Google) is misleading since it covers an older version of Google Forms that is no longer available. As far as I know, there is [no way to adjust the font size](https://support.google.com/docs/forum/AAAABuH1jm0CMpe0IzlM8k/?hl=en&gpf=%23!topic%2Fdocs%2FCMpe0IzlM8k) in the [current version of Google Forms](https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2018/06/use-new-theme-options-to-customize-and.html). The documentation only mentions how to change the font type, not the size.

Ref:

- [Change the theme or font of your form](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/145737?hl=en)